# Convert Shape from awt to Shape in javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt, oracle-spatial

I want to display Shape on Pane in JavaFx. I am using oracle JGeometry object selected from spatial database, it has a method createShape() but it returns java.awt.Shape. 
Is it possible to create JavaFx object also so easily? Maybe I am just blind but I haven't found anything and don't want to program too much stuff on top. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java only supports a handful of shapes, so it is not very difficult to write a little converter but if all you want to do is to draw the AWT shapes on a JavaFX canvas, then maybe this library can be helpful: http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/

Comment: I also want to convert it back to JGeometry and save it to database when I move it  on the Pane (I don't use canvas for now) Okayit is best to just create some class with other basic shapes and create them accordingly to JGeometry shapes. It will be sufficient I think. Thank you for the link.